# Why does my binary search fail/return the wrong values?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int binary_search(int arr[], int x, int sz)
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = sz - 1;
    while (left < right)
    {
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] < x)
        {
            left = mid + 1;
        }
        else if (arr[mid] > x)
        {
            right = mid - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return mid;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int n;
    int sz1 = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);
    printf("Enter the number you want：");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    int ret = binary_search(arr1, n, sz1);
    if (ret == -1)
    {
        printf("Missed");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d\n", ret);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I enter `10` or `11` or other bigger number, it always prints `0`.
Anyone knows how can I get a `9` when I enter `10`, and get a `Missed` after I enter `11` ?

Comment: `while (left < right)` ==> `while (left <= right)`

Comment: AND, `return -1;` at the bottom of the function... The `while()` condition may break the loop ("not found") but there's no `return` at the bottom of the function. (The compiler should have warned you about this.)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- function `binary_search` does not have a `return` statement in case the loop is exited.  You should add `return -1;` after the `while` loop.
- the test `while (left < right)` assumes the entry at index `right` is excluded from the search, yet you define `int right = sz - 1;` which explains why `10` is not found in your tests.  You should instead define `int right = sz;`
- computing `int mid = (left + right) / 2;` is risky for large arrays as `left + right` might cause an arithmetic overflow. You should instead write:

  ```
      int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
  ```
- you should test the return value of `scanf_s("%d", &n)` to detect and report invalid input.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int binary_search(int arr[], int x, int sz) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = sz;
    while (left < right) {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] < x) {
            left = mid + 1;
        } else
        if (arr[mid] > x) {
            right = mid;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(void) {
    int arr1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int sz1 = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);
    printf("Enter the number you want：");
    int n;
    if (scanf_s("%d", &n) != 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int ret = binary_search(arr1, n, sz1);
    if (ret == -1) {
        printf("Missed\n");
    } else {
        printf("%d\n", ret);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One key discussion of the overflow danger is Google's blog from 2006 — [Extra, Extra — Read All About It: Nearly All Binary Searches and MergeSorts Are Broken](https://ai.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html).

Answer (score 1):

The code had two problems preventing obtaining the intended results:

1. `while (left < right)` wherein the `<` should have been `<=`
2. A missing `return -1;` to indicate the search function did NOT find a matching value in the sorted array.

Below is an annotated re-write that incorporates a few *improvements*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for "EXIT_???" values

// rearranged parameters to follow: "Find 'x' in 'array' of this 'size'"
// use of "const" to indicate variables' values are not altered.
int binary_search( const int x, const int arr[], const size_t sz ) {
    size_t lft = 0; // correct datatype (size_t) for "unsigned" array indexing
    size_t rgt = sz - 1;

//  while( lft < rgt ) // incorrect in OP code
    while( lft <= rgt ) {
        const size_t mid = (lft + rgt) / 2;

        if( arr[mid] == x )
            return mid; // "early return" for "found" easy to spot in code

        // note: no "else" required following a "return" like that...
        if ( arr[mid] < x )
            lft = mid + 1;
        else {
            if( mid == 0 ) // prevent -'ve index (recall 'size_t' is unsigned)
                break; // or "return -1;" right here...
            rgt = mid - 1;
        }
    }

    return -1; // missing from OP code...
}

int main( void ) {
    const int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    const size_t sz = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]; // no need for "()"

    int n;
    printf( "Enter the target number: " );
    if( scanf_s( "%d", &n ) != 1 ) { // ALWAYS verify return values from system calls
        fprintf( stderr, "Bad entry\n" );
        return EXIT_FAILURE; // simple exit; no recovery.
    }

    const int idx = binary_search( n, arr, sz );
    if( idx == -1 )
        printf( "Missed" );
    else
        printf( "arr[%d] contains %d\n", idx, n ); // explanatory message

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note: While this works for smaller arrays, it may be possible that a value is "found" at an index that is larger than a returned `int` can represent.

A minor change would be to declare the function returning a `size_t`, and have it return `sz` (the impossible index of an element *one beyond* the end of the array). This improvement would ripple on to require changes in `main()` to receive a `size_t` return value, and the comparison for "found"/"not found" would need to be adjusted, too. An exercise for the reader...

PS: An alternative style of curly braces for the purpose of demonstration.

Comment: There is a corner case that will invoke undefined behavior: if `sz` is `0`, `binary_search` should return `-1`.  Also changing the type of `sz` to `size_t` is vain since the return type is still `int`, with a smaller range, especially on 64-bit systems.

Comment: Also `const size_t mid = (lft + rgt) / 2;` should be `const size_t mid = lft + (rgt - lft) / 2;` to avoid problems with large values of `lft` and `rgt` on some architectures.

Comment: @chqrlie All good points... I'll leave the `sz == 0` case to be detected by the calling function (like `arr == NULL`)... Tough crowd!! :-)